# How can I control a program via Apple accessibility?

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I'm currently trying to control my Mac to be able to open the `Minecraft` application, and tap buttons such as `Single Player`, `Create New World`, etc.

These buttons should have accessibility options on them, so I'm looking to be able to open Minecraft and press these buttons via code. Ideally it would be `Python` code, but if there are any other languages like `Objective-C`, these would be useful too.

I've searched for ways to do this without interacting with the `GUI`, but the world generation seems to be dependent on code the Minecraft application delicately executes upon pressing buttons like `Create New World`, which isn't accessible via an API.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Mac Automation Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Would you be able to post it as an answer? Someone had posted AppleScript too, but deleted it before I could accept!

Comment: Link-only answers are not allowed. It is allowed to post your solution as an answer to your own question.